# Sort in SOQL by column in the inner query

Tags: apex, soql

I want to sort Accounts using the field in Opportunity in my SOQL.

This is the query which selects Accounts and Opportunities. I want to order the Accounts using MAX of Opportunity.ExpectedRevenue field.

```
Select Id, Name (Select Id, ExpectedRevenue from Opportunities) from Account where Id in :listVar and ownerId = :currentUser
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: You realize there will potentially be multiple values? Do you want to sort by MAX/MIN/AVG? Can you please **[edit]** your post to clarify expected behavior?

Comment: Why you are not doing soql on opportunity with order by and use relation to get account fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just query on the `Opportunity` object instead. You can use aggregate queries if you want just one record per parent. That would look like:

```
SELECT Account.Name, MAX(ExpectedRevenue) maxRevenue
FROM Opportunity
WHERE AccountId in :listVar
AND Account.OwnerId = :currentUser
GROUP BY  Account.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to come at it from the other direction.

```
SELECT Id, ExpectedRevenue, Account.Id, Account.Name 
    FROM Opportunity where Account.Id in :listVar and Account.OwnerId = :currentUser 
    order by ExpectedRevenue DESC
```